# how to get the correct resource id for an android device from uiautomator?

Tags: appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

i have question about resource ids in uiautomator :

```
btn="id:/image_button_cancel"
```

why sometimes we add ".*" what is the meaning of that ?

```
btn="id:/image_button_cancel.*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a regular expression. The dot means any character and the asterisk means zero or more repetitions.

So using btn="id:/image_button_cancel.*" will match any resource id that starts with "id:/image_button_cancel".

## Example (matched ids):

```
id:/image_button_cancel
id:/image_button_cancel_action
```

## Example (not matched ids):

```
id:/cancel
id:/image_button
```

Search about regex to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get your question exactly. Can you please elaborate more?

**.*** is used to match the resourceId by regex.

So **id:/image_button_cancel.*** means it will match any resourceId which starts with **id:/image_button_cancel**

For Ex,

id:/image_button_cancel_1

id:/image_button_cancelQuick

Like this...